# How to sort a JSON to values a-z - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-native, search

I saw similar questions this title but they are very diffrent from what I need. 
 I'm trying to sort my JSON, so when I "for"/search it, it will find values by the order of a-z.

For example when I search for the Song_Name: **"The"** it will bring me these result in this order - The Beatles..., The Clash..., The Doors..., The Rolling Stones. 
My JSON looks goes like this:

```html
 [{"Song_ID":"6","Song_Name":"Zsis - Champagne Supernova","Song_File":"http://songs/Oasis_Champagne_Supernova.mp3","Image":"http://artists_images/Oasis.jpg"},{"Song_ID":"8","Song_Name":"Oasis - Don't Look Back In Anger","Song_File":"http://songs/Moses_Dont_Look_Back_In_Anger.mp3","Image":"http://artists_images/Oasis.jpg"},{"Song_ID":"10","Song_Name":"The Rolling Stones - Like A Rolling  Stone","Song_File":"http://songs/Rolling_Stones_Like_A_Rolling Stone.mp3","Image":"http://artists_images/Rolling_Stones_Stripped.jpg"},{"Song_ID":"11","Song_Name":"Doors - People Are Strange","Song_File":"http://songs/The_Doors_People_Are_Strange.mp3","Image":"http://artists_images/The_Doors.jpg"}]
```

In other words to sort it by its "Song_name" a-z.

I tried with any one of these functions but each of one of them give me **an empty search result** (without these functions the search is working fine):

```js
sortSongsByName = (stringSongs)=>{
  stringSongs.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.Song_Name.toLowerCase() < a.Song_Name.toLowerCase();
  });
};


sortAllSongs = songsList => {
     songsThings(a,b) 
      a = a.Song_Name.toLowerCase();
      b = b.Song_Name.toLowerCase(); 
      return a > b ? 1 : b > a ? -1 : 0;
}


function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.Song_Name.toLowerCase() < b.Song_Name.toLowerCase())
    return -1;
  if (a.Song_Name.toLowerCase() > b.Song_Name.toLowerCase())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}


function sortThings(a, b) {
  a = a.Song_Name.toLowerCase();
  b = b.Song_Name.toLowerCase();

  return a > b ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : 0;
}
```

componentDidMount -

```js
  this.state = {
         songs: [],
       };

     componentDidMount = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("@MyMusic:songs").then(value => {
          let songsList = JSON.parse(value);
          songsList = JSON.stringify(songsList);
          songsList.sort(sortThings); // calling the function
          this.setState({ songs : songsList });
          });
      };
```

Part of the search function -

```js
   SearchSong = () => {  
this.songsList.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.Song_Name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.Song_Name.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(songsList)
        let strKeyword = this.state.searchRes.replace(/["  "]/g, "");
        musicList = [];
        songsLength = this.state.songs.length;
        if (strKeyword == "" || strKeyword == " ") {
          return;}
        for (i = 0; i < songsLength; i++) {
```

The console.logs of "songsList" and "songs" after the function called, are 'undefined'.

- Question 
 
Can I sort a state with these functions? for example-

```js
this.setState({ song: song.sort(sortThings)});
```

If any more code is needed please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your sorting function isn't returning the sorted array. You need to put a `return` in front of the `stringSongs.sort`:

```
sortSongsByName = (stringSongs)=>{
  return stringSongs.sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.Song_Name.toLowerCase() < a.Song_Name.toLowerCase();
  });
};
```

EDIT: After OP edited their question, I have the following to add:

The fact that these are returning `undefined` confirms my answer above. And to answer the additional question of whether you can `setState` using the return value of a function, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yea it works thanks, But has a little bug in it  - when I press only one letter, the first result is  a song name with diffrent letter starting. For example "T" - brings me first result - "Radiohead" only after, the songs are in the right order. Do you know any solution ?